# How to render a component under the Vue instance

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to create a Nuxt module that won't interfere to main Nuxt application. I will create another Vue instance, and mount it under body. Like a child node to __nuxt div. And there's no problem on creating that app, and mounting it under body element. Also I'm creating a component under that app, with the [.component()](https://vuejs.org/api/application.html#app-component) function. The problem is including that component in my Vue instance. I've my component value, created with .component() function, and I've my  which is mounted on my `mountPoint`. I need to create that component under the  instance whenever a user clicks a button. So I try `component.mount(mountPoint)`, but I get a Vue warn (as expected) saying me that `An app is mounted on mountPoint` and I have to unmount it first. I've searched docs and Stack, but I can't seem to find a utility or API function that will make me render that component under my App.

Here's my code:

```
const componentSubprocess = createApp(/*creating instance here*/);

const component = componentSubprocess.component("toast", /*component*/);

component.mount(mountPoint);
/*
This is part where I get a warning.
I need to render this component under my componentSubprocess, which is my <App>
I can't seem to get it to work, nor find a possible solution.
*/
```

Comment: If you're using Nuxt then the question is specific to it, not Vue in general. Consider explaining your case, this is likely XY problem. Since Nuxt is isomorphic framework, multiple instances don't make much sense on server side, how do you expect them to work exactly?

Comment: This module have nothing to do with Nuxt instance, and it's actually better for it to work directly under the body element (styling makes more sense that way), that's why I decided to work with a seperate Vue instance. Also, I've already explained my problem, which is being unable to render a component on an app instance.

Comment: As I said, this may be XY problem, and you'll have better chances asking a broader question. There are conventional solutions for what you're trying to do, primarily a teleport, https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/features/teleports/#example-body-teleport . Without changing the way it works, another instance should likely be Vue and not Nuxt, didn't try that but don't  see reasons for this to not work

Comment: So you're suggesting that I should create a SFC, and teleport it under body with Nuxt. Honestly, that makes sense. But I've one problem here. I need to pass data with props while importing that component in a Nuxt.js plugin file.

`import Component from "./Component.vue`

Also to note, the second instance is Vue, not Nuxt.

Comment: You can pass props where you use the component, i.e. in <teleport>. It's unclear what your case exactly is. It appeared the first time that there's a restriction that it shouldn't be Nuxt instance, and it's unknown why. It would make more sense to use Nuxt everywhere in this case. It's unknown what's "mountPoint", and what's the exact error (it's not expected). Please, update the question with all relevant info on that. There's seems to be no such problem in general, so this is very specific to your case, and currently only you know the details.

Comment: Well, are you sure that you actually read the text on the question? 
I don't have any error, that's first of all. And I've actually told what `mountPoint` is and what warn I get in the text.  https://imgur.com/a/qW5aSNn

Comment: I actually did, and I believe these things are needed to be clarified if you're interested in solving your problem. You can be sure that you didn't provide enough info - unless you're able to answer your question. In your snippet mountPoint variable  is undefined. It will throw with an error. It's unknown what the real value is and how it's related to existing DOM and app. You've got a *warning*. I believe that "An app is mounted on" is not a real message but a loose interpretation of it, please, don't retell messages but quote them. The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you could mount your component in another mount point. just like below：

component.mount('#another-mount-point)

But if you only trying to mount to root mount point, it's hard

Comment: I have to mount it under my instance, which is mounted on my `mountPoint`. Any ideas on how to do that?